# index.xml does not update on netlify

Tags: hugo, netlify, blogdown

I'm trying to update my blogdown site to have an 'r' rss feed and show the entire posts. The index.xml file does get updated correctly but it does not show in the deployed version on netlify.

The xml updates and can be seen in github [here](https://github.com/samcarlos/new_blogs/blob/master/public/categories/r/index.xml) but won't show up at the rss feed site [here](https://samcarlos.netlify.com/categories/r/index.xml)

Since I updated code I expected the website's rss feed to change accordingly but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post relevant code/artifacts here

Comment: I posted a link to the relevant `index.xml` sites. There's a lot of code there and im not sure whats relevant or not.

Comment: @user3655819 please read how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce it. Too much work. Will go back to use blogger :(